# OfficeJs displayDialogAsync - check if i have an open dialog window

Tags: office-js

I have an excel add-in. I placed two content-pane from my add-in and i would like to open a dialog from it.

One excel allow only one dialog window in same time.

When i open a dialog window before i have an ajax request to server, but if i can not open the dialog window then i no need ajax call.

I tried to save information to localStorage, but if excel is hurm and reload itself, localstorage will show that dialog is open in turn this is wrong information.

How can I check if I have an open dialog window?

Thank you in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 2):

The `displayDialogAsyc` method will return error 12007 if there's already a dialog open. You can test for this and have your code branch if 12007 is returned. For some details, see [Errors from displayDialogAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/dialog-handle-errors-events#errors-from-displaydialogasync).

Comment: I understand your solution, but my code look like this:

1: ajax call
2: when response recieve from ajax -> dialog open.

My problem: i should not create ajax call if i can not open dialog window

Comment: in office for Windows and mac you don't get 12007, and it is possible to open multiple dialogs but when you close the dialog you get 12006 error.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution, but i think it is not the best.

Firstly i try to open a dialog with a not trusted site url.

If i get 12004 error it means i can open a dialog window.

If i get 12007 error it means i can not open dialog window beacuse already opened a dialog from this host window.

It seems like 12007 check is runs earlier than the 12004 check.